# How do i withdraw Eth from a contract i created

Tags: transactions, contract-design, metamask, myetherwallet

New to blockchain.. havent a clue.. I managed to create a new contract with Eth. I moved money from MyEtherum Wallet to Metamask and into a contract, somehow? I have no coding experience but need someone to help with getting my Eth back out of the contract..
From looking around myetherwallet i found a ABI/JSON interface and now wondering if this is where the withdrawal code goes. If so anyone any idea what it might be?

Is this the correct way to withdraw Eth from a contract to a wallet?

Im new at this.. have no clue.

Using 'MyEtherwallet' and 'Metamask'
Also have the address of the contract.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you provide the code of the contract you sent your eth to? Whether you can withdraw your eth from the contract or not (and how) depends on the contract.

Comment: I have the contract address but no script or code.

Comment: How did you `create a new contract`? Do you know if you deployed to the mainnet or a testnet?

Comment: I have no idea. i was going to deposit Eth into an Ethereum Gold contract and when i went to deposit via metamask, it auto created a contract and my Eth went there. i can see the smart contract using Etherscan will all the Eth movements but have no idea how this happened or how to retrieve the Eth, I would even pay for someone to help me..

Comment: Could you link us to the contract you created and sent your ETH to?

Comment: Contract 0xf6aB4331FB8Dde0bb10F58BD0cc818514736a74f just search this on Etherscan

Comment: Once you deposit into a contract due you need to exchange the Eth to a Token?

Comment: Steven V - The new contract was on mainnet.